# maximum value row wise in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 5 columns in my mysql table:

```
name s1 s2 s3 s4
A    1   2  3  4
B    15  6  7  8
```

I want to calculate the column name and value which holds the maximum value out of s1, s2, s3, s4 within a row, i.e.,

```
name col value
A    s4  4
B    s1  15
```

I can't use max because it calculates column wise maximum. How am I supposed to do this?

PS: Schema cannot be changed because in all the other use cases, I have to display information name wise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change your database structure

Comment: Is there something like a pivot in mysql?

Comment: @RogueCoder group by is used as pivot in mysql.

Answer (score 4):

The correct data structure for your table would be something like this:

```
name | column | value
-----|--------|------
A    | s1     | 1
A    | s2     | 2
A    | s3     | 3
A    | s4     | 4
B    | s1     | 15
B    | s2     | 6
B    | s3     | 7
B    | s4     | 8
```

and then your query would be like this:

```
select *
from tablename
where (name, value) in (select name, max(value)
                        from tablename
                        group by name)
```

but how do you want to manage a tie (two columns with the same maximum value?)

If you cannot change your data structure there is still something you can do, getting the max value it's easy:

```
select name, greatest(s1, s2, s3, s4)
from tablename
```

but getting also the column name is a little tricky:

```
select
  name,
  max_value,
  case when p=1 then 's1'
       when p=2 then 's2'
       when p=3 then 's3'
       when p=4 then 's4'
  end as col_name
from (
select
  name,
  greatest(s1, s2, s3, s4) as max_value,
  field(greatest(s1, s2, s3, s4), s1, s2, s3, s4) as p
from
  tablename
) s
```

or this:

```
select
  name,
  greatest(s1, s2, s3, s4) as max_value,
  substring_index(substring_index('s1,s2,s3,s4', ',', field(greatest(s1, s2, s3, s4), s1, s2, s3, s4)), ',', -1) as p
from
```

Comment: I have updated the question. I can't change the table structure because of other functional requirements.

Comment: @proprius did you try my second solution?

Comment: yes.. I am using the greatest function now but I cannot use the substring_index part.. It is because of the reason that my column names might have `'` or `,`.

Comment: @proprius if your column names might have `,` it's a problem... can you use any other character for example `|` ? then you can use `substring_index(substring_index('s1|s2|s3|s4', '|', field(greatest(s1, s2, s3, s4), s1, s2, s3, s4)), '|', -1)`

Comment: that uncertainty will always be there. To avoid this, I am using if else over the columns

Comment: @proprius yes, but if the column names are dynamic then it's better to change your database structure to my first solution, if it is not you should know in advance whether the column names contains any special characters

Comment: my column names will contain special characters for which a fixed set cannot be defined until it comes. That is why for me the best way is to use if else and not substring

Answer (score 0):

you can use this , but notice that in this case if you got the max value in two different columns you will get null values if you want to get other value we can change this in the case

```
select name,
       case when s1>s2 and s1>s3 and s1>s4 then 's1'
            when s2>s1 and s2>s3 and s2>s4 then 's2'
            when s3>s1 and s3>s2 and s3>s4 then 's3'
            when s4>s1 and s1>s2 and s1>s3 then 's4' as col
       case when s1>s2 and s1>s3 and s1>s4 then s1
            when s2>s1 and s2>s3 and s2>s4 then s2
            when s3>s1 and s3>s2 and s3>s4 then s3
            when s4>s1 and s1>s2 and s1>s3 then s4 as value
from my_table
```

Comment: Is there a way I can combine these 2 case statement in 1, i.e., case returns multiple values? Also, concat is one way but I don't want to go for it.

Comment: each case give you one column and since you want two different column you needs two cases

Comment: you can combine them and separate the values with comma or other character but you will receive them in one column, in your question you asked two different columns